# SymmetricDS Could Not Find Batch to Acknowledge as OK

Tags: symmetricds

Im doing bi-directional push on 3 tier nodes.

Why on 1st and 2nd tier nodes are spamming error like this:

1st tier node is logging error:

`"IncomingBatchService - Skipping batch x"
"DataLoaderService - x data and x batches loaded during push request from 2nd tier. There were x batches in error."`

2nd tier node is logging error:

`"PushService - Push data sent to 3rd tier"
"AcknowledgeService - Could not find batch to acknowledge as OK"
"PushService - Pushed data to 3rd tier. x data and x batches were processed"`

After checking DBs:

On 2nd tier node the batch is pointed to 3rd tier node with LD status and reload channel. No batch in same id that pointed to 1st tier node

On 1st tier node the batch is pointed to 2nd tier node with OK status an reload channel

Help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there must be logs on target nodes with exceptions thrown by data loader trying to load batches in error. find them and they'll tell what's wrong

there's a mistake in the 3rd tier node. `sync.url` should be `http://<3rd_tier_node_IP>/sync/<engine.name>`

Comment: I didn't see any necessary exceptions. I just see error at 2nd tier node "PushService - Could not communicate with 3rd tier node at http://<sync.url_of_1st_tier_node> because: Connection reset", "DefaultOfflineClientListener - Failed to connect to the transport. http://<sync.url_of_1st_tier_node>", "PushService - There was a failure while pushing data to 3rd tier node. x data and x batches were processed"

Comment: there's your answer. that node is offline. make sure central node can be pinged (ping central_node_ip), ssh-ed or telneted with: telnet central_node_ip 8080

Comment: no, there is error at 2nd tier node that wants to push to 3rd tier node but it pushed to 1st tier node sync.url. I tried telnet to 1st tier node IP and it's connected. The sync.url and registration.url is correct

Comment: could you post registration and sync URLs from engines/*.properties files from all 3 tier nodes?

Comment: sure, the registration.url is pointed to http://<2nd_tier_node_IP>/sync/<engine.name>, and the sync.url is blank

Comment: is this the 3rd tier node?

Comment: ah sorry misreading,
1st tier node: registration.url is blank, sync.url is http://<1st_tier_node_IP>/sync/<engine.name>.
2nd tier node: registration.url is http://<1st_tier_node_IP>/sync/<engine.name>, sync.url is http://<2nd_tier_node_IP>/sync/<engine.name>.
3rd tier node: registration.url is http://<2nd_tier_node_IP>/sync/<engine.name>, and the sync.url is blank

Comment: there's a mistake in the 3rd tier node. sync.url should be http://<3rd_tier_node_IP>/sync/<engine.name>

Comment: ah it works. I'm following the sample configuration but it also works on push and pull action, why?